# HttpResponseCache - Exclude caching response based on mime type

Tags: android, caching

I want to use  HttpURLConnection and HttpResponseCache for caching http response but limit what to cache based on mime time. So I only want HttpResponseCache  for JSON response and not for images, for which I am using different caching . Is there a way to tell HttpResponseCache   to exclude caching based on mime type or restrict caching based on request uri.

Comment: Just starting with `HttpResponseCache` myself. Any news on that topic?